# What is the difference between transient document and document in OpenCMIS?

Tags: apache, sharepoint, alfresco, opencmis, apache-chemistry

I'm not sure of the difference. 
When is a transient document is requested, is the document automatically checked out and is it something similar to a private working copy?

Comment: Please give some more details this does not seems enough

Comment: There are two classes called **TransientDocument** and **Document** in OpenCMIS. What is the difference between them? What is the use of TransientDocument Class?

Answer (score 1):

Do not use TransientDocument. It has been deprecated, see [the JavaDoc](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/0.9.0/maven/apidocs/org/apache/chemistry/opencmis/client/api/TransientDocument.html).

Jeff